# How does one feed a list of files into an app with appscript and Python?

Tags: python, macos, applescript, finder, sourceforge-appscript

Get your newb-shields up, I'm about to sprinkle you with some.
I'm trying to get Photoshop CS4 to open a folderful of JPEG images with AppScript+Python, which could be described like so in BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in `ls ~/Desktop/test`; do
    open -a "Adobe Photoshop CS4" $F
    # proceed to mutilate the image appearance
done
```

I'm failing at the `ls ~/Desktop/test` stage.  I'd really like to ask Finder to list a folder for me, and feed the result into Photoshop one at a time to process them.
A JavaScript equivalent with Adobe's ExtendScript bridge would be:

```
#target photoshop
var folder = Folder("~/Desktop/test");
var images = folder.getFiles();
for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i] instanceof File && images[i].hidden == false) {
        var doc = app.open(images[i]);
        // do something to the image here
        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
}
```

I can get me a `document_file` object with a horribly silly contraption like `x = app('Finder').home.folders['Desktop']().folders['test']().items()[0]`, but that turns out to be a really silly object.  Trying to `app('Adobe Photoshop CS4').open(x)` this object will throw an `OSERROR: 1230`, with a `MESSAGE: File/Folder expected`.

*(Uh-oh, this `document_file` actually responds to `URL()`, so `File.makewithurl(x.URL())` can be fed into `open()`)*

Ehm, having solved that, is there a way to actually do this by asking Finder for the list of files in a given folder, specified by a *UNIX path*?

Comment: Why does this have an applescript tag? Typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop's open command requires an alias object (or list of alias objects).

```
from appscript import *

folder = '/path/to/folder'

ps = app('Adobe Photoshop CS4')

for f in app('Finder').items[mactypes.Alias(folder)].files.get(resulttype=k.alias):
    ps.open(f)
    # do stuff here...
```

Comment: Also, rather than using the Finder's scripting interface, OS X provides a hidden scriptable app, `System Events.app`, that includes a `Disk-Folder-File` suite with various properties.  And, in some cases, it might just be simpler to use Python modules, i.e. os.listdir et al, to do file searching and then use appscript's Alias to form the proper reference.